# Touchpad doesn't work

Tags: touchpad

Please, help me. Even after the OS upgrading my touchpad doesn't work properly. Everything is OK about swiping, but in the case I'd like to tap I have to use buttons (it means I have to use buttons instead of using the touchscreen, because it simply doesn't react).
Maybe it happens because of any bug? Is there anybody who also had such an experience?

```
synclient -l
    LeftEdge                = 43
    RightEdge               = 1045
    TopEdge                 = 38
    BottomEdge              = 666
    FingerLow               = 1
    FingerHigh              = 1
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 56
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 100
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 25
    HorizScrollDelta        = 25
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.15444
    TouchpadOff             = 2
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 0
    RBCornerButton          = 0
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 0
    TapButton2              = 0
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 1
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 0
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 6
    VertHysteresis          = 6
    ClickPad                = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
TapButton1              = 0
TapButton2              = 0
TapButton3              = 0
```

For some reason all the tapping options (single-finger, double-finger and triple-finger tapping) are disabled.

Edit `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

Find this section:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection
```

And add the following lines before the `EndSection` line:

```
Option "TapButton1" "1"
Option "TapButton2" "3"
Option "TapButton3" "2"
```

This will bound the one-finger tap to the left click, the double-finger tap to the right click and the triple-finger tap to the middle click;

Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and reboot.